# generator for keras in infinite loop

Tags: python, keras, generator

All,

I have a problem with this piece of code from the book "deep learning with Python" by Francois Chollet:

```
import numpy as np
import os
import sys
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

def generator(data, lookback, delay, min_index, max_index,
shuffle=False, batch_size=128, step=6):

   if max_index is None:
      max_index = len(data) - delay - 1
   i = min_index + lookback
#   for it in range(1):
   while True:
      if shuffle:
         rows = np.random.randint(
              min_index + lookback, max_index, size=batch_size)
      else:
         if i + batch_size >= max_index:
              i = min_index + lookback
         rows = np.arange(i, min(i + batch_size, max_index))
         i += len(rows)
      samples = np.zeros((len(rows),
                   lookback // step,
                   data.shape[-1]))
      targets = np.zeros((len(rows),))
      for j, row in enumerate(rows):
        indices = range(rows[j] - lookback, rows[j], step)
        samples[j] = data[indices]
        targets[j] = data[rows[j] + delay][1]
   yield samples, targets

data_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(),'jena_climate')

fname = os.path.join(data_dir, 'jena_climate_2009_2016.csv')
f = open(fname)
data = f.read()
f.close()
lines = data.split('\n')
header = lines[0].split(',')
lines = lines[1:]
print(header)
print(len(lines))

float_data = np.zeros((len(lines), len(header) - 1))
for i, line in enumerate(lines):
       values = [float(x) for x in line.split(',')[1:]]
       float_data[i, :] = values

# temp = float_data[:, 1] 
# plt.plot(range(len(temp)), temp)
# plt.show()

mean = float_data[:200000].mean(axis=0)
float_data -= mean
std = float_data[:200000].std(axis=0)
float_data /= std

lookback = 1440
step = 6
delay = 144
batch_size = 128

train_gen = generator(float_data,
lookback=lookback,
delay=delay,
min_index=0,
max_index=200000,
shuffle=True,
step=step,
batch_size=batch_size)

val_gen = generator(float_data,
lookback=lookback,
delay=delay,
min_index=200001,
max_index=300000,
step=step,
batch_size=batch_size)

test_gen = generator(float_data,
lookback=lookback,
delay=delay,
min_index=300001,
max_index=None,
step=step,
batch_size=batch_size)

# samples,targets=next(train_gen)

val_steps = (300000 - 200001 - lookback)
test_steps = (len(float_data) - 300001 - lookback)

# print(val_steps)

def evaluate_naive_method():
    batch_maes = []
    for step in range(val_steps):
        samples, targets = next(val_gen) 
        print(step)
        preds = samples[:, -1, 1]
        mae = np.mean(np.abs(preds - targets))
        batch_maes.append(mae)

    print(np.mean(batch_maes))

evaluate_naive_method()
```

The code defines a generator function to generate samples for the temperature forecasting example. However, with my python 3.6.8 installation under Ubuntu linux, the generator remains caught in an infinite loop and the loop that generates the validation data never executes.  I have seen similar issues here. Obviously, it is a small problem with the correct treatment of generators in python 3. 
Does anyone know how to circumvent this ?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is because the indentation of the yield statement is messed up. It should be enclosed within the `while True` loop to yield a batch in each iteration of the loop. Change:

```
while True:
    ### other code
yield samples, targets
```

to

```
while True:
    ### other code
    yield samples, targets
```